# How do websites like www.violetstreet.com put video in the website?

Tags: video, web

Websites like violetstreet.com and vine.co put video in the background and text and search button over it. How can I do such a thing?  Also what video format they use as its not .gif.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML :

```
<video id="bg_video" src="video.mp4" autoplay />
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var index = 1,
      playlist = ['video.mp4', 'second_video.mp4', 'third_video.mp4'],
      video = document.getElementById('bg_video');

  video.addEventListener('ended', rotate_video, false);

  function rotate_video() {
    video.setAttribute('src', playlist[index]);
    video.load();
    index++;
    if (index >= playlist.length) { index = 0; }
  }
</script>
```

CSS :

```
#bg_video { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```